# Traversing an array with a regular expression doesn't work as intended

Tags: java, arrays, regex

### Short intro:

In my code I prompt the user for a chosen month, or a chosen year, and this value is then included as a Regular Expression in traversing an array holding the climate measurements - which I have already scanned from a text-file and put into a String-array.

Beneath is a sample of the measurements, there is approx. 1800 measures in my text file and I have checked that the array is setup properly, the item count checks.

> 1874 Januar 3.2
>  1874 Februar
>   1.6
>  1874 Marts 2.9
>  ......
>  2005 Oktober 11.1
>  2005 November 6.3
>  2005 December 2.7

I have included a sample piece of code beneath - **At the very bottom I've bulletpointed the code which I from the debugger know isn't working as intended.**

**Edit: Posted full code insted of a sample**

```
public class Klimadata {

    public static String[] data;
    private static boolean choose_year;
    private static boolean choose_month;
    private static int yearChoice;
    private static int monthChoice;
    private static String[] MONTH = { "", "Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August",
            "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        data = init();
        while ((choose_year == false) || (choose_month == false)) {
            System.out.println("Choose Month or Year (m/y)");
            String choice = scan.nextLine();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                choose_year = true;
                System.out.println("Chosen year, now enter which (int, 1874-2005):");
                choice = scan.nextLine();
                while (true) {
                    yearChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
                    if ((yearChoice >= 1874) && (yearChoice <= 2005)) {
                        printData(yearChoice);
                        System.out.println("Program exiting.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Please choose a year, use 4 digits.");
                        choice = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {
                choose_month = true;
                System.out.println("Chosen month, now enter which (int, 1-12):");
                choice = scan.nextLine();
                while (true) {
                    monthChoice = Integer
                            .parseInt(choice); /* Casted from String to int */
                    if (((monthChoice >= 1) && (monthChoice <= 12))) {
                        printData(monthChoice);
                        System.out.println("Program exiting.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Please choose a month, use 1 or 2 digits.");
                        choice = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Neither m or y has been chosen, try again!");
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    /* Prints our selection to the terminal */
    private static void printData(int choice) {

            /* Year has been chosen */
            if (choice > 1000) {
                for (int z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
                    if (data[z].matches(Integer.toString(choice)))
                        System.out.println(data[z]);
                }
            }
            /* Month has been chosen */
            else if (choice <= 12) {
                for (int z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
                    if (data[z].toString().matches((MONTH[choice])))
                        System.out.println(data[z]);
                }
            }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    /* Initializes an array of the weather data */
    public static String[] init() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String temp = "";
        /* Imports the data into a String */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Timber\\workspace\\Codejudge_5\\src\\vejrdata.txt"));
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            temp = temp.concat(scan.nextLine() + "\n");
        }
        /* Splits the String into a String[] */
        data = temp.split("[\\r\\n]+");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        return data;
    }
}
```

- if (data[z].matches(Integer.toString(choice)))
- if (data[z].toString().matches((MONTH[choice])))

These two conditions do not print out any text to the console, as I intended the code to run.

Comment: This snippet seems to miss a lot of things. Where is the declaration of MONTH f.e.?

Comment: Will fix ASAP. Sorry, I wasn't sure it was necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you're wrapping your content in parenthesis, "("+choice+")" instead of just "choice"? Can we see your regex pattern too?

Comment: Yes, the pattern is very basic, for year it is: (dddd) where d is a digit. For months it is: (dd)
Appropo "("+choice+")" this is what I tested should fullfill the criteria for the regex. I used an online tool.

Comment: Ok, but why are you wrapping 'choice' in parantheses? If the .txt file contains lines like "1874 Januar 3.2" and you look for (choice), f.e. (1874), it wont work?

Comment: I'm a big noob to regex. I tried removing it, nonetheless, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, tested it. You can just use String.contains();
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-

if (data[z].contains(Integer.toString(choice)))
                        System.out.println(data[z]);